# Search function with flags

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a quick search bar to search a table populated by an SQL database. The search will not search the table, but will generate SQL statements and search the database. I need to implement a search function using PHP that will use flags to stop the search. This is my code so far:

```
//THIS CODE WILL EXECUTE WHEN THE SEARCH BUTTON IS PRESSED
if($_REQUEST['btnsearch']){

    if(isset($_POST['quicksearch']) and !empty($quicksearch)){

        $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='alerts_table'
        AND column_name IN('name', 'year','make','model','alert','date')";

        $retvalues = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $data = array();
        //LOOP POPULATES THE ARRAY WITH THE CURRENT COLUMN NAMES.
        for($counter = 0; $counter <= $row=mysqli_fetch_array($retvalues, MYSQL_ASSOC); $counter++){

            $string = $row["column_name"];

            $data[$counter] = $string;
        }

        $length = count($data);

        $flag = 1;

        while($flag == 1){

            for($x = 0; $x <= $length - 1; $x++){

                $sql3="SELECT * FROM alerts_table WHERE $data[$x] = $quicksearch";
                $retvalues2=mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

                if(!empty($retvalues2))
                {
                    //POPULATE THE TABLE WITH RESULTS HERE !!!!!!!!!

                    $flag = -1; ///HOW CAN I BREAK THE LOOP???

                }
            }
        }
    }else{
```

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you are asking?

Comment: yes, i apologize,  i need to know how i can use flags to break out of a loop when a match is found. for example, if the query returns a match..stop the loop

Comment: Use the `break` statement to break out of a loop. That should be explained in any PHP tutorial.

Comment: @Barmar you should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @sdsmith It's not my question.

Comment: My apologies! @vhdz04 you should edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHP [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) documentation:

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.
>
> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many
>   nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of. The default value
>   is 1, only the immediate enclosing structure is broken out of.

In your case you have two loops; a `while` loop and an inner `for` loop. You can set your flag in your inner loop to a value that will stop the `while` loop, and then use a `break` to stop the `for` loop.

```
$flag = 1;

while($flag == 1){
    for($x = 0; $x <= $length - 1; $x++){
        // ...
        if(!empty($retvalues2))
        {
            $flag = -1; // set while condition to false
            break; // break out of for loop
        }
    }

    // execution continues here after break
    // end of while body, start next loop iteration
    // $flag == 1 => false, and the while loop will end
}
```